# Selenium Web Scraping Id missing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to gather the data from the http://maharain.gov.in/ site. I have written the below script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re
import csv,sys,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time 




def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath,driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


chromepath= '/home/swapnil/Downloads/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)

start_time =time.time() 
base_url = "http://maharain.gov.in/"
driver.get(base_url)
driver.switch_to.frame('MenuFrame')
driver.find_element_by_name("QueriesCirclewise3").click()
time.sleep(3)
print("Done")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu"]/input[10]').click()
time.sleep(3)
print("Done")
# driver.find_element_by_name("PastQueriesCirclewise6").click()
time.sleep(3)
print("Done")
# driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(3)
print("Done")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("ContentFrame"))


# dropdown_menu_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selyear")) 
# select_year = [option.text for option in dropdown_menu_year.options]
# select_year = [t for t in select_year if t !='Select']
# select_year = [ '2015', '2016', '2017']

time.sleep(3)
print("Done All ")
dropdown_menu_state = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selstate")) 
select_state = [option.text for option in dropdown_menu_state.options]
select_state = [t for t in select_state if t !='Select']

dropdown_menu_dist = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("seldist"))   
select_dist = [option.text for option in dropdown_menu_dist.options]
select_dist = [t for t in select_dist if t !='Select']

dropdown_menu_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selmonth"))
select_mon = [option.text for option in dropdown_menu_month.options]
select_mon = [t for t in select_mon if t !='Select']

i = 0
year=str(2018)
# for year in select_year:
if not os.path.exists(year):
    os.makedirs(year)
for state in select_state:
    for dist in select_dist:
        if not os.path.exists(year+'/'+dist):
            os.makedirs(year+'/'+dist)
        for month in select_mon:
            print (i)
            # dropdown_menu_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selyear")) 
            # dropdown_menu_year.select_by_visible_text(year)
            dropdown_menu_state = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selstate")) 
            dropdown_menu_state.select_by_visible_text(state)
            time.sleep(1)
            dropdown_menu_dist = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("seldist"))   
            dropdown_menu_dist.select_by_visible_text(dist)
            if(dist=='Wardha' or dist=='Washim' or dist=='Yavatmal'):
                # time.sleep(2)
                dropdown_menu_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selmonth"))
                dropdown_menu_month.select_by_visible_text(month)
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.find_element_by_name("btnshow").click()

                time.sleep(2)
                print("Done")
                driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > embed'))
                if (check_exists_by_xpath('//*[@id="tableID"]',driver)):
                    tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tableID"]')
                    soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source)
                    table = soup.select_one('table')
                    data = [[td.text for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.find_all("tr")]
                    file_name = year+'/'+dist+'/'+year+'_'+dist+'_'+month+'.csv'
                    print(file_name)
                    f = open(file_name,'w', newline='')
                    writer =csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerows(data)
                    f.close()
                    i+=1
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("ContentFrame"))

print ( time.time() - start_time)
print(i)
```

But each time I run the code it gets stuck at different locations with errors like missing selector id "selstate" or "body > embed" not present, which may run correctly in the next run without any changes to the code and may get stuck at the different location.

I have tried adding driver implicit wait and thread sleep with value set to 5 and less.Please point out what should be the correct measure to make it run in one go and where should be the wait or sleep statements to be added or any other changes if required.

Comment: This is obviously a timing problem. You need to use explicit waits to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I agree but adding wait at all the conflicting locations still had the same issue.

Comment: I don't see any selectors related to `selstate` or `body > embed` in your code trials. What are your exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I am trying to get the data from the given site from the QueriesCirclewise option in the right column. It downloads data of all year, district wise rainfall.